# FileNotFoundException when after adding a Class Library assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I do have an ASP.NET MVC Core app and would like to add a Class library in my project. 
I added it in my project via "Add Reference" > "Browse" > select DLL and done.

[image]

I added it on code like

```
using PagarMe; // works good on code
```

And I was able to compile and run the app. however when the user goes to a page where the lib is referenced then I got the fallowing error.:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PagarMe.Pcl, Version=2.0.6372.16631, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What I already done.

- I checked the output bin folder and the Dlls files are there.
- Both DLLs are compiled with "Any CPU" configuration.
- I tried PCL and non-PCL Version.
- App Target framework: .NETCoreApp 1.1
- Default Class Library Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.5.
- Portable (PCL) Class Library Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.5 and ASP.Net Core 1.0

What can I do in order to use Class Library or PCL library into my Core App?

Comment: Turn on fusion logging.  That'll tell you where the binder is looking for the assembly, and what it's expecting to find.  Then you figure out why it isn't there.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework / .NET Standard Library are you targeting with the class library? And is that version compatible with the version of .NET Core you are using?

Comment: When you add a dll as a reference it copies the dll to the bin folder whenever the dll gets changed or doesn't exist.  Does the dll expect the Pcl File to be located in same folder as the dll?  If so you will need to copy the Pcl to the bin folder.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch edited question with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET Core you no longer use Portable Class Libraries, but you target the correct version of the [.NET Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library). Some PCL or Shared Classes may use some unsupported 
references.

To solve this please try one of this:

**1. Rebuild your Class Library to target .NET Standard**. .NET Standard  1.6, for instance, is supported by both .NET Core 1.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

> .NET Standard can be thought of as the next generation of Portable Class Libraries (PCL). The .NET Standard improves on the experience of creating portable libraries by curating a standard BCL and establishing greater uniformity across .NET runtimes as a result. A library that targets .NET Standard is a PCL or a ".NET Standard-based PCL". Existing PCLs are "profile-based PCLs". (Taken from the documentation)

**2. Target your app to .NET Framework.**
You could build an ASP.NET Core application to target the full .NET Framework in stead of .NET Core only. This gives you the advantages of ASP.NET Core, without the limits of .NET Core.

*ASP.NET Core != .NET Core*

Comment: Are you saying that I'm not able to use PLC libs into my Core App? what about the Default Class Library targeting .Net Framework 4.5. ?

Comment: A default Class Library also does not play nice with .NET Core since it _could_ use API's that other .NET Core runtimes do not support. That's what the .NET Standard is for: defining a set of API's a platform supports. Targeting .NET Standard is easier than using a PCL with .NET Core.  

Please look at the link I added in my answer, since it also has a PCL Compatibility part at the end where it explains if and how a specific PCL profile is compatible.

Comment: I understand. Once i'm not able to rebuild the Class library (cause it is no mine) Is there something else that I can do?

Comment: @DanielSantos You could build a ASP.NET Core application that targets the full .NET Framework in stead of .NET Core. This gives you the advantages of ASP.NET Core, without the limits of .NET Core.      

ASP.NET Core != .NET Core

Comment: That was perfect. Can you please add this to your answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: @DanielSantos Done ;)